How can I hide widgets that should not be visible when packing in_ a scrolling frame?
I'm coding an application in Python with TKinter and I'm having this problem where the contents of portions of a scrollregion that should be invisible are being displayed.
I've built the following test code as a demonstration (modified only slightly from https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/):
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

array=[]

def ResizeImage(image,new_size=(300,500)):
    tempImage=Image.open(image)
    card=tempImage.resize(new_size)  #Don't re-use variable for somereason, and do in extra lines?  Test later.
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(card)

root = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(50):
    
    array.append(ResizeImage("C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/Frederick/python projects/junk/Ballroom_Dance.png"))
    if i%2:
        y=ttk.Label(root, image=array[-1])
        y.pack(in_=scrollable_frame)
        x=ttk.Label(root, text="Sample scrolling label")
        x.pack(in_=scrollable_frame)
    else:
        y=ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, image=array[-1])
        y.pack()
        ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Sample scrolling label").pack()
container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()


What I see is that when a Label is a child of the scrollable frame everything works normally, but when the same Label is instead a child of root being placed with y.pack(in_=scrollable_frame) the items are visible even when they shouldn't be, although the scrolling otherwise functions fine.
In my actual program I need the widgets being placed in the scrollable frame to be nearly top-level, because the drag and drop implementation I'm using only works when the target shares an ancestor with the object to be dropped.  Is there a way I can keep these widgets children of root but make them vanish correctly when scrolling? If not, is there another way to enable drag-and-drop between distantly related scrollable frames that only share some much higher-level ancestor?

I'm not sure I've used the scrollview tag correctly; please let me know if that should have been a different tag

When you create your widget, you set the master. This master will be responsible for children clipping, no other widgets will do this. Therefore, when you use pack (in_= …), you only change the "position" of the widget, but the root still the one does the cutting and you can't change it once it is set. You might be able to cheat, but it probably won't be easy. So I would advise you to change your drag-and-drop system as this is more likely to be done.

Do what @ DanyaK says but if you really want, you can call .lift() on widgets that are supposed to be on top of you pack(_in=...) widget.

Why are you using duplicates root.mainloop() and canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True) and  scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

You can use .configure for ttk.Label. So you need duplicate widgets.

It is better to post the code on the drag and drop stuff since it is the cause of using in_.

@acw1668 Okay. I will do that in another question, since it would change this one so much.

@acw1668 Actually, I figured out how to refactor it to not use in_ when writing up the question, so I'll just do that.  Thanks for the help, though.
